# How to put .gif files in the build directory

Tags: c++, macos, qt, chess

I have to make a chess game with graphics and this is a part of my code for the board and a chess piece. I have made the chess board and now I am trying to add in a chess piece which is an image I have downloaded. I have the code but I need to somehow put the chess piece image into my build directory for the piece to actually appear on the board. I am using QT creator on a mac and can not figure it out.

```
for (int x=0; x<8; ++x) {
    for (int y=0; y<8; ++y) {
        if((x+y+1)%2==0) {
             paint.fillRect(x*44,y*44,44,44,QColor(177,113,24));
        } else {
              paint.fillRect(x*44,y*44,44,44,QColor(233,174,95));
        }
        QImage image;
        image=QPixmap("wrook.gif").toImage();
        paint.drawImage(0*44,7*44,image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see an error? If so, what is the error? Have you tried putting `wrook.gif` in the same directory as your built executable?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to put the wrook.gif file in any directory. I've been trying but nothings worked.

Comment: Check your operating system to see if there is a command line prompt and what the command is for copying files.

Comment: You may want to place the `gif` file in the same directory as your executable.

Comment: Search the internet for "how to copy files osx".

Answer (score 2):

You can use resource files to add different types of files to your Qt application without dealing with their origin in the hard-drive.
If you are using Qt Creator just click "File -> New file or Project" select "Qt -> Qt Resource file" add prefix (they are like directories inside the resource file) and copy there your images.
Them to load those files use this code :

```
QImage image;
image=QPixmap(":/some_directory/some_image.gif").toImage();
```